# Operation not supported on socket - sendto(2) in ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets

I try to type a ruby UDPsocket server side practice and here is a given client side code:

```
require 'socket'
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8888
flag = Socket::MSG_OOB # MSG_PEEK , MSG_WAITALL
client = UDPSocket.new
client.send("udp socket test message", flag, ip, port) code here
```

But when I run that file, the command line told me

```
Operation not supported on socket - sendto(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8888 (Errno::EOPNOTSUPP)
```

I just searching all ruby doc and every website that I cab reach, but I don't see any explanation there, is anyone can help?

btw, here is my server side code, I am not sure it is right or not, maybe take a look:

```
require 'socket'
socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.bind('127.0.0.1',8888)
data = "udp socket test message"
data, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024) 
puts "From addr: '%s', msg: '%s'" % [addr.join(','), data]
socket.close
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man send](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send):

> MSG_OOB
>   Sends out-of-band data on sockets that support this notion (e.g., of type SOCK_STREAM); the underlying protocol must also support out-of-band data

Thus you are trying to use a flag intended for TCP (SOCK_STREAM) on a UDP (SOCK_DGRAM) socket. No wonder it complains that the flag is not supported.